# PDF Artifact PGFPlots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am using TeXStudio with LuaLaTeX, and here's my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{float}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta, automata, positioning, matrix, calc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}    
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \captionsetup{skip = 5pt} %default is 10pt; I am doing this to make use of pages more efficient; if I didn't do this, then some figures would go onto the next page, and leave a lot of space at the end of the current page
        \pgfplotsset{grid style={dashed,gray}} %Both grids for this figure ONLY
        \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right,
        declare function = {r1 = 0.8; 
                            A1 = 4*r1;
                            B1 = 1000*r1 - 4225;
                            C1 = 62500*r1;
                            r2 = 1.2;
                            A2 = 4*r2;
                            B2 = 1000*r2 - 4225;
                            C2 = 62500*r2;
                            R41 = (-B1 - sqrt(B1^2 - 4*A1*C1))/(2*A1);
                            R42 = (-B2 - sqrt(B2^2 - 4*A2*C2))/(2*A2);
                            R43 = (-B2 + sqrt(B2^2 - 4*A2*C2))/(2*A2);
                            R44 = (-B1 + sqrt(B1^2 - 4*A1*C1))/(2*A1);}]
            \begin{semilogxaxis}[
            width=12cm,
            height=9cm,
            xmin=10^0,xmax=10^6,
            ymin=0,ymax=0.5,
            %axis lines = left, %if this is activated, then the tick marks on up and right part of plot will disappear
            xlabel = {$R_4$ ($\SI{}{\ohm}$)}, ylabel={$\eta$},
            %every axis y label/.style={at={(0,1)},anchor=south},
            %every axis x label/.style={at={(1,0)},anchor=west},
            xmajorgrids,
            ymajorgrids,
            samples=1000,
            grid=both] %More samples = smoother curve
                \addplot [color = blue, thick, domain = 1:R41+1] {(4*x^2 + 5225*x + 62500)/(9*x^2 + 9725*x + 2131250)};
                \addplot [color = red, thick, domain = R41:R42+1] {(4*x^2 + 5225*x + 62500)/(9*x^2 + 9725*x + 2131250)};
                \addplot [color = blue, thick, domain = R42:R43+10] {(4*x^2 + 5225*x + 62500)/(9*x^2 + 9725*x + 2131250)};
                \addplot [color = red, thick, domain = R43:R44+10] {(4*x^2 + 5225*x + 62500)/(9*x^2 + 9725*x + 2131250)};
                \addplot [color = blue, thick, domain = R44:10^6] {(4*x^2 + 5225*x + 62500)/(9*x^2 + 9725*x + 2131250)};
                %The top four \addplot commands had the right boundaries slightly over the bounds for the constraint set because if stopped right at, say, R41, then there will be a small gap between red and blue curves. The succeeding \addplot command will write over the preceding curve.
            \end{semilogxaxis}
        \end{tikzpicture} 
        \caption{This plot.}
        \label{eta}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If we zoom in, we see an artifact:

[image]

Is there some PDF setting in TeXStudio to get rid of the artifacts in general (and in future tex compilations)?

Comment: If you set the samples to 101, which is more than sufficient to generate a nice plot, the feature is not there.

Comment: Hmmm interesting I had to add more samples for a high frequency sinusoid because things looked jagged. I wonder why adding more samples contributed to the artifact. I thought that it had to do with the pdf settings in TeXStudio.

Comment: I do not really *know* what is going on, but if one draws line segments of considerable width and infinitesimal length, a small inaccuracy may get enhanced. To give you an example, if you draw a line from `(x,f(x))` to `(x+dx,f(x+dx))`, and there is a small inaccuracy in the computation of `f(x)` and/or `f(x+dx)`, the slope of the segment, `(f(x+dx)-f(x))/dx`, will be very wrong. For larger `dx`, this is less problematic. Since the segments will be connected, features of this type may arise. Note that I am only guessing, I have no evidence for my statements.

Comment: Oh, since `dx` is small, the denominator is small, so if `f(x)` is off (there are obviously numerical errors, can’t have infinite precision), this pretty much amplifies the error. That seems to be a reasonable guess, though

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be solved in the comments.